# The page.route is not working in playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I have this code below to intercept http request:

```
await page.route('**', route => {
     console.log("ROUTES>>>>>>>>>>>>> ");
     const request = route.request()
     console.log(request.url(), JSON.stringify(request.headers()));
     return route.continue();
});
```

But seems like upon running it is not going inside that page.route because the console does not print the console.log that I put.

Does anyone has any idea on how to make that work? Thank you

Comment: This should work. Can you share a [mcve]? What request(s) are you trying to intercept? Maybe you're adding this code after the request is already sent?